# in python how to count the number of arguments passed after a specific argument?

Tags: python, linux, bash, centos

in python how to count the number of arguments passed after a specific argument ?

Explanation :

```
[user]$ command1 -h 192.168.1.1 -p 8888 -t 50 -u -c ...etc  main.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

here when using sys.argv in main.py the number of arguments is 12 ( or more, it may differ every time )

i want to count only arguments after main.py so only : `arg1 arg2 arg3` which is "3" .

Any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's `command1`?  It doesn't look like it would be `python`, and if it's not then not only could you potentially get some help from that program, but a direct answer to the question posed depends on how that program is invoking `main.py`.

Comment: If you are invoking `main.py` correctly, `arg1` et al should be the *only* three arguments in `sys.argv`.

Comment: @chepner Actually i'm not calling it at all it's command1 who does by a config file.

Comment: Then `command1` should be fixed.

Comment: If `command1` is passing *all* its arguments to `main.py`, how can you be sure of the order in which the user of `command1` provides the arguments? Couldn't it just as easily be `command1 main.py -h ...`?

Comment: @chepner Exactly i don't know in which order that the user will pass the arguments but what i do know for sure that he must do an '-a' to begin passing the three arguments wanted. that's why the solution of Adid worked. 

i didn't use command1 main.py -h ... by convention. 

Thanks , i really shouldn't ask for XYProblem .. my bad.

Comment: @chepner Could you please show me  how the question could be asked ? 

for more propre questions in the futur. Thanks

Comment: Maybe give an example for how the sys.argv looks when the script is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the index of `main.py` within the `sys.argv`, and then slice accordingly:

```py
main_index = sys.argv.index('main.py')
arguments_after_main = sys.argv[main_index:] # Should contain only arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: This seems to make some pretty big assumptions.  Note that the OP asks for a way to perform the argument count in `main.py`, and that there is no information on what `command1` is and little on what it does.

Comment: OP says that `sys.argv` contains `main.py` in their case, so I'm working off that assumption. You're right that it won't find anything if `main.py` is _not_ in `sys.argv`, but that was not the question that was asked.

Comment: This answer also assumes that `command1` does not reorder the arguments, and if the question is about the argument list as it is presented to `command1` then this answer assumes that that program does not add any arguments after `main.py` that would be visible to the latter.  The question contains clues that these assumptions might not hold.

Comment: I don't know of a way to find what arguments are after a different argument if I don't know the order of the arguments. This is my best go at a solution from what I understood from the OP.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Actually the command1 is the command that calls the script ( main.py) so here there is no main.py in my command ( the command it self calls it by a configuration file )

Comment: OP has an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info): you are solving the Y.

Comment: Yes, @Dexter, that is exactly my point.  *How* `command1` starts `main.py` matters here.  If, for example, it runs `/bin/env/python main.py arg1 arg2 arg3` then this answer works fine, but is overkill, as in that case, `sys.argv.index('main.py')` will *always* evaluate to 0.  But also, what you just said is inconsistent with the question.